# QGIS plugin closing all open PyQt dialogs

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

In my QGIS3 plugin I need to close all open PyQt5 dialogs. The structure of my plugin is like the following code. To be clear, when I call `runCloseDialogs()` I want to close both dialogs opened by `run()` and `run2()` if they are open. How can I do this?

```
def run(self):  
  self.dlg = Dialog()       
  self.dlg.show()

def run2(self):
  self.dlg2 = Dialog2()
  self.dlg2.show()

def runCloseDialogs(self):
  #close all open dialogs here
```

Comment: Do you want to close all open dialogs in the plugin OR all open dialogs opened in some specific methods (like run and run2)? Is the question about method-based dialogs or dialog-based dialogs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CASE 1**: If dialogs are created in the main `class` defined in main module of the plugin,

- First, find all attributes of main `class`. (`vars(self)`)
- Then, check if any is `QDialog` and is visible. If it is, hide using `setVisible(False)`

```
def runCloseDialogs(self):

    items = vars(self)

    for i in items:
        item = items[i]
        if isinstance(item, QDialog) and item.isVisible(): 
            item.setVisible(False)
```

**CASE 2**: If the plugin has any widget (GUI) which contians other Qt elements (for example QPushButton) and dialog window is opened by that element, in this case, dialog window is (probably) child of main widget (GUI). In this case, `self` stands for GUI.

- First, find all `QDialog`s instances of the plugin.
- Then, check if it is visible. If it is, hide using `setVisible(False)`

```
def runCloseDialogs(self):

    for dlg in self.findChildren(QDialog):
        if dlg.isVisible(): 
            dlg.setVisible(False)
```

The script above close all dialogs defined in the plugin's GUI.

**CASE 3**: If you want to close only `self.dlg` and `self.dlg2`, you can use the following lines:

```
def runCloseDialogs(self):

    if self.dlg.isVisible():
        self.dlg.setVisible(False)

    if self.dlg2.isVisible():
        self.dlg2.setVisible(False)
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much. I was asking about the first case, but your answers are both usefull.

Comment: It says: 'Plugin' object has no attribute 'findChildren'

Comment: Ok. I thought `run` method was defined in a GUI class. I've editted the answer.

Comment: Thank you, your answers are always very complete