# How to remove all resources loaded from QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I used the QGIS Plugin Builder to create a plugin where the *main.py* file imports dockwidgets and class from its own file and from other files. A button on the toolbar executes the `run(self)` function in *main.py* where it loads the imported dockwidgets, classes, connecting buttons to functions etc.

Another button on the toolbar closes the plugin by executing the `onClosePlugin(self)` function. This function only closes dockwidgets loaded from *main.py* (so not from other files) and disconnects its buttons. The imported classes are untouched. However, when I close the plugin, QGIS continues to run but a lot slower than usual. It also takes longer to close down, sometimes I get an error report. I'm guessing this is because of all the resources my plugin loads but is still in memory when the plugin is closed.

**How can I remove/unload all resources that have been imported/loaded by the plugin?**

When I import dockwidgets and classes from other files, I use the following in my *main.py*

```
from some_Dockwidget import someDockwidget
from general_Class import generalClass
```

Which are then called in `run(self)`:

```
self.someDockwidget = someDockwidget()
self.generalClass = generalClass()
```

---

I found [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353598/qgis-plugin-closing-all-open-pyqt-dialogs) which closes all QDialog boxes. I have used the following to close all dockwidgets but can it be adapted to close/unload/delete everything that has been imported/loaded?

```
items = vars(self)
for i in items:
    item = items[i]
    if isinstance(item, QDockWidget):
        item.close()
```

Comment: I feel that the question is a bit opinion based, and finding **the** correct answer will be hard, but if you pointed out a bit better, what exactly your requirements are, this should be perfectly answerable and valueable =)

Comment: @Erik thanks, I'll edit my question :D

Comment: Garbage collection of Qt widgets is even less obvious than normal Python garbage collection. You may need to use the deleteLater method of Qt objects - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deletelater-method-in-pyqt5/. You might have better luck asking this on a more programming oriented forum, like StackOverflow